# Event Dispatcher for WCF call-backs

Tags: wcf, callback

I have a server that needs to keep a small number of clients in sync.  Whenever there is a change of state at the server, all the connected clients must be informed.

- I am planning to use a “callback
  contract”,
- I can get hold of the
  callback reference for each client on
  the server by using
  GetCallbackChanel().
- I then need
  to manage all these client channel
  reference and call all of them when
  needed.

So far so good however:

- I don’t wish to block the server, so calls to the clients must be none blocking
- Errors calling the client must be logged and coped with

**Is there a standard WCF component to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not a *standard* WCF component for this, at least through .NET 3.5.  I can't speak to what may be available in .NET 4.0.

That said, there is a pretty straightforward way to do this.  Juval Lowy, author of [*Programming WCF Services*](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521325), describes how to do this using his WCF-based [Publish-Subscribe Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx).

Basically, the idea is to create a separate WCF event service that resides in the same hosting application as your server (e.g., Windows service, IIS).  When the state of your server changes, you *publish* the state change to the event service.  The clients that need to be kept in sync *subscribe* to this same event via the event service.  In effect, the event service becomes a broker for your server to notify clients of whatever events your server publishes.

The article I listed above has a code download, but you can also get the Publish-Subscribe Framework and a working example for free from his website, [IDesign.net](http://www.idesign.net).  Here is the link to the [download](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11#Operations).  You may need to scroll your browser up just a little bit to see it as I believe their internal hyperlink is wrong.